# Avoiding Explicit Lambda?

Tags: scala, scalaz

Given the following:

`(0, 0).some >>= (x => move(5,5)(x))`

where `move` has type `(Int, Int) => (Int, Int) => Option[(Int, Int)]`, how can I avoid explicitly specifying the argument, `x => move(5,5)(x)` **without** using for-comprehension notation.

Comment: If `move` has type `(Int, Int) => Option[(Int, Int)]`, what is the second argument `x` supposed to be?

Comment: can you show the definition of `move`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

how about eta-reducing the argument to `>>=` as in:

```
(0.0).some >>= move(5,5)
```